# Create a Generic Object in C#

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

How do I create a class that should look like this:

```
public class DynamicObject<T> 
{
   public T PassedObject { get;set; }
   string RepositoryMessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

In my Repository I can return an object if it gets a result from the db. This is supposed to be placed in the T. But if I don't get any result, then the T should be null and the RepositoryMessage should have a message. Below is the sample code for the repository

```
public async Task<DynamicObject<UserModel>> GetUser(SomeObject object) 
{
   UserModel um = new UserModel();
   DynamicOBject do = new DynamicObject<UserModel>();
   DB CALLS HERE....
   var responseCode = cmd.Parameters["@ResponseCode"].Value
   var responseMessage = cmd.Parameters["@ResponseCode"].Value
   if (response == 0) 
   {
     ....
     um.FName = reader.GetString(0);
     um.LName = reader.GetString(1);
     // The DynamicObject should now look like this:
     PassedValue = UseModel and the RepositoryMessage = string.Empty
     ....
   } else {
     do.PassedObject = null;
     do.RepositoryMessage = responseMessage;
     // The DynamicObject should now look like this:
     PassedValue = null and the RepositoryMessage = WHATEVER the responseMessage is from the SP.
   }
   return do;
}
```

I don't know if there is an existing technique for this. But this is the only way I think I can get the message of the database and pass it along to the controller and pass it to the client through the error like this => return BadRequest(respository.RepositoryMessage);

### Edit

I don't know if this is correct or a standard practice, but this is what I came up with:

```
public class GenericResponse<T>
{
    public string RepositoryMessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public T? ModelToReturn { get; set; }
}

public async Task<GenericResponse<ApplicationUser>> AuthenticateUser(UserLoginModel model)
{
    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
    GenericResponse<ApplicationUser> response = new GenericResponse<ApplicationUser>();
    try
    {
        using (_connection = new SqlConnection(_helper.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            using(var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "UserLogin";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = _helper.GetCommandTimeout();

                var pUserName = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@UserName",
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    Size = 20,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    Value = model.UserName
                };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pUserName);

                var pPassword = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Password",
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    Size = 35,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    Value = model.Password
                };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pPassword);

                var pResponseCode = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@ResponseCode",
                    DbType = DbType.Int16,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pResponseCode);

                var pResponseMessage = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@ResponseMessage",
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    Size = 75,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pResponseMessage);

                await _connection.OpenAsync();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var responseCode = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ResponseCode"].Value.ToString());
                var responseMessage = cmd.Parameters["@ResponseMessage"].Value.ToString();

                if (responseCode == 0)
                {
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while(reader.Read())
                        {
                            user.FirstName = reader.GetString(0);
                            user.LastName = reader.GetString(1);
                            user.UserRole = reader.GetString(2);
                        }
                    }
                    response.ModelToReturn = user;
                    response.RepositoryMessage = string.Empty;
                } else
                {
                    response.ModelToReturn = user;
                    response.RepositoryMessage = responseMessage;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _helper.LogErrorMessage(ex.StackTrace, Models.LoggerModel.LoggingType.Error);
        response.ModelToReturn = user;
        response.RepositoryMessage = "An error has occured in loggin in";
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing all of this? It seems very... silly. Is there a reason you're not using a conventional ORM like EF? What is the significance of `RepositoryMessage`? What is so _dynamic_ about `DynamicObject<T>` considering it's statically-typed?

Comment: How will you distinguish between query failure and the DB returning a null-like value for a query?

Comment: I just want to pass the message from the database to the controller then to the client if it doesn't get an object. Let's say the response from the db says "I don't want to give you a reply". I want that reply brought back to the controller so I can pass it to the client.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 There are much better approaches for passing side-channel information than this approach...

Comment: If a query failed, then I just catch it then in the RepositoryMessage put in the reason.

Comment: @Dai Can you share it please. Am just experimenting here. If there is a technique or a standard way of doing it, I am all for that.

Comment: Generic object? Generic repository? Reinventing the wheel and running into every pit same along the way? Why not just use Entity Framework? Especially with regards to login credentials and stuff, that's the place where many security vulnerabilities came from over the years. Just use Microsoft Identity.

Comment: The `AuthenticateUser` method should return the `Task<ApplicationUser>` in the case of a normal workflow. And (re)throw an exception with the desired message in case of any error.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Dand that's right.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a general rule, but I use in `Cotroller`:

```cs
return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result.Data);
```

for a good query, status code `200` returns only data.

Based on validate or using `try` `catch` for query, I return the best matching statuses, the `Data` now as error message, not just `BadRequest`